# Validating Date on Date Time Now

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi i am trying to validate my through a textbox control for asp.

I want it to vaildate whether its empty, a date that is today or in the future not the past, and that the date format is correct MM/DD/YYY.

I have wrote this code for that:

```
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPickupDate.Text) Then
        lblError.Text = lblError.Text & "<BR>You must enter in the field Pickup Date."
        lblError.Visible = True
        rtn = False
    Else

        If txtPickupDate.Text > DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY") Then
            lblError.Text = lblError.Text & "<BR>You must enter in a valid date for Pickup."
            lblError.Visible = True
            rtn = False
        Else
            Dim Pickup As Date
            If Date.TryParseExact(txtPickupDate.Text.ToString(), "mm/dd/yyyy", _
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, _
                                  Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, Pickup) Then
            Else
                lblError.Text = lblError.Text & "<BR>You must enter the Pickup Date in the format of MM/DD/YYYY."
                lblError.Visible = True
                rtn = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

However it does not work on the

> If txtPickupDate.Text > DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY") Then

Comment: dont do text compares on date data.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/czRPsJ

Comment: why don't you parse the date string?

Comment: @Plutonix Unless it is ISO 8601 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and the date is between [1000 and 10000).

Comment: Parse `txtPickupDate.Text` to a date and compare that (date to date)

Comment: I tried 
            If DateTime.Parse(txtPickupDate.Text) > DateTime.Now Then and it doesn't work still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
It will validate that a parse-able date was entered and then check only the date portion for determining whether or not it is in the past, present, or future.

```
Dim enteredDate As DateTime
If Not DateTime.TryParse(txtPickupDate.Text, enteredDate) Then
    ' Invalid date entered.
Else
    ' Valid date entered.
    ' Validate against the date part only.
    If enteredDate.Date < DateTime.Today Then
        ' Date is in the past.
    Else
        ' Date is today or in the future.
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks i endded up fixing it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
    Dim Today As String = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

    'Due Date 
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPickupDate.Text) Then
        lblError.Text = lblError.Text & "<BR>You must enter in the field Pickup Date."
        lblError.Visible = True
        rtn = False
    Else

        If txtPickupDate.Text < Today Then
            lblError.Text = lblError.Text & "<BR>You must enter in a valid date for Pickup Date."
            lblError.Visible = True
            rtn = False
        Else
            Dim Pickup As Date
            If Date.TryParseExact(txtPickupDate.Text.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", _
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, _
                                  Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, Pickup) Then
            Else
                lblError.Text = lblError.Text & "<BR>You must enter the Pickup Date in the format of MM/DD/YYYY."
                lblError.Visible = True
                rtn = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Dont use string to compare data data. `txtPickupDate.Text < Today` will fail for a "1/31/2015" Pickupdate compared to say, #12/18/2014#